# Expected in: flat namespace after install brownie

Tags: python, error, brownie

i installed brownie with pipx but when i type any command i get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lorisfacchinetti/.local/bin/brownie", line 5, in <module>
    from brownie._cli.__main__ import main
  File "/Users/lorisfacchinetti/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/brownie/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from brownie.project import compile_source, run
  File "/Users/lorisfacchinetti/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/brownie/project/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .main import (  # NOQA 401
  File "/Users/lorisfacchinetti/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/brownie/project/main.py", line 44, in <module>
    from brownie.network import web3
  File "/Users/lorisfacchinetti/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/brownie/network/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .account import Accounts
  File "/Users/lorisfacchinetti/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/brownie/network/account.py", line 12, in <module>
    import eth_account
  File "/Users/lorisfacchinetti/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eth_account/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from eth_account.account import (  # noqa: F401
  File "/Users/lorisfacchinetti/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eth_account/account.py", line 8, in <module>
    from cytoolz import (
  File "/Users/lorisfacchinetti/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cytoolz/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .functoolz import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/lorisfacchinetti/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cytoolz/functoolz.cpython-310-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyGen_Send
  Referenced from: /Users/lorisfacchinetti/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cytoolz/functoolz.cpython-310-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/lorisfacchinetti/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cytoolz/functoolz.cpython-310-darwin.so
```

i tried to reinstall pipx, brownie, cytoolz but nothing has changed. Has anyone had the same problem?